# CMake Error：Error occurred while communicating with CMake server

Tags: android

When I new a CMake project by the Android Studio,it occures a problem when I open it by the first time:

> Error:Error occurred while communicating with CMake server. Check log F:\JNI\app.externalNativeBuild\cmake\debug\armeabi\cmake_server_log.txt for additional information.

below is the cmake_server_log.txt

```
CMAKE SERVER: 
CMAKE SERVER: [== "CMake Server" ==[
CMAKE SERVER: {"supportedProtocolVersions":[{"isExperimental":true,"major":1,"minor":1}],"type":"hello"}
CMAKE SERVER: ]== "CMake Server" ==]
```

below is the .cpp file

```
#include <jni.h>
#include <string>

extern "C"
JNIEXPORT jstring

JNICALL
Java_example_com_jni2_MainActivity_stringFromJNI(
        JNIEnv *env,
        jobject /* this */) {
    std::string hello = "Hello from C++";
    return env->NewStringUTF(hello.c_str());
}
```

It's the origin project created by the Android Studio,I didn't change anything;and I have installed the CMake and NDK.
Why this error occured?

Answer (score 1):

t's caused by the upgrade of default cmake in gradle, from 3.6 to 3.10. See https://github.com/XiaoMi/mace/issues/301#issuecomment-452544100 for details.

Comment: Please post the relevant parts of the solution from the link in your answer, in case the target of the link becomes unavailable.